# string variable with ltr and rtl letters

Tags: php, html

I have text that contain hebrew (rtl) and english (ltr) letters. it's song with chords above the words.

the problem is with the chords - because the site is rtl than I see the chords messy.
Is there any way to display the words line RTL and the chords LTR ( while they all be straighten to the right)?

here is a link to example
http://www.israeli-guitar.com/chords/index.php?artist_id=189&song_id=1115

First row should be: Bbm Db F#

Answer (score 1):

You can use css: [direction:](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_direction.asp)

- direction:rtl;
- direction:ltr;

---

You could work with `<span></span>` element.
For the chords: `text-align: right; direction: ltr;`
For the text:   `text-align: right; direction: rtl;`